# SQL Bulk Insert With Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a bulk insert into one table that holds ID references from another table.

Example:

```
Name    | Address     | Country_ID | City_ID
John Doe| 123 Fake St | 1          | 2
```

On my bulk insert CSV file I have many different Country_IDs and City_IDs which I rather not populate by hand.

I want the CSV to have values like:

```
John Doe| 123 Fake St | USA        | Seattle
Jane Doe| 321 Real St | USA        | Los Angeles
```

How can I populate the CSV file with the actual country/city name and when it gets inserted it goes in as the actual ID from the Country and City table?

I suspect some sort of join is required.

Comment: what have you tried? we can't write all the code for you, you need to put something down for us to help with.

Comment: I don't understand your question:  you start saying you are trying to bulk insert into a table, and you end asking how to populate a CSV file.   Can you edit your question and make it more specific as to which part you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a staging table and bulk insert the data into that table. Once the data is loaded in SQL, you can join the table to the relevant tables and insert the data into the destination table.